# How to store in-house apps if we bought the enterpise license for iphone developer program?

Tags: iphone-developer-program

I'm new to IOS. I understand there are standard and enterprise iphone developer program. Standard program allows the developed apps to store at iTune Store. Where to store in-house apps for enterprise program? Do we need to cater servers to house these in-house apps? If yes, what type of servers we need? Web or App servers??

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the developer program you can see the answer here (The description should answer your question):
[The Three ways to distribute iPhone Enterprise apps - iTunes, iPhone Configuration Utility, or Wirelessly from a Web Server](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html)